# PHP cURL - how to check the return data type from fpassthru?

Tags: php, curl, fopen

First, how do I call this type of data that returned **successfully** from **fpassthru**?

> ��m�U�Vmo�6�O��\%��W�&0Xۤmծ�aZ&�'�^C����1$m��ꮪ���O>`��>�c;;U�km��G���`A0>C���LhH�&�`���w��#�W�lv�ZUl��~_��ŝg�^{Ww�0�+��%J�/A�!��AD��8"�P��3�K�D�$ �K�V;�����,Uf{Өn��6EW�}�ԧϭ�@g����������X?aI�$¶��1��s&3�8%���#�S�/:�z
>   �80������s��Je��撟O�*�O`*.@
>   �5^.{,v��.*�[�����iZ���4e1.u�Pm�\��MU˅�Bf��Y.�f���k>���C���z�И]i�ت)}i�^��JYz֪2z�=����l��^w��|�*���^'�}亩V�;6y*``��]A�� ����*ߗ�6_w���Mg�#��
>   �����۟0W��w���v�L����4�DS)b�""�3F9��h��
>   ƶ&t%���i�,*��?��a�i,m��e��̗���䒢Dʄeh*�ǒ=W��Q�d<)i{��%�X�QEO�:ƛm��o�J��P�'noKS�T���U&?q�u�+��V��FM;m��j-��ih�1�l;��N�o�Ԏ�t=��l��>G�[Cݬ��'d�����0�!3��s�P�dI�S�RI1�����O�7V,�|�%$~Lx6�g"LJRNq"� i
>   ��18�mL(G0�����8�%a��cȌ���kB/�}����,G���C 'q�x!X\�"A!C��H_H)p�+�g��ٷ�����*������ޫA�6�G�
>   6p���d�$*m�;�7�U,l��T��������~�v|P~Q��E��T'�����
>   ��qb$##����/)�h%
>   ?��1�Q�Ә>�kB?#h"�Q<   9�p�$���O|8�"FI,�L��?���&�����[��k�5gB������&}�^-��~��^�Ms;��p�����r�f�__��?����:#��3��Z=�!s{X���[��.pA�h�Tƌ��˺�v��'}�7���֫�qd)ӝ��t����7�����(

They are the output from this file - `download.php`,

```
$file = "G:/../xxx.tgz";

// Open the file in a binary mode
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

// Dump the tar and stop the script
$success = fpassthru($fp);

fclose($fp);

if(!$success) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to downlonad');
}
```

Then how do I check at cURL whether I get this type of data or others?

For instance, `curl.php`,

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/.../download.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

var_dump(gettype($result)); // string 'string' (length=6)
```

But if I `echo 'hello world'` in `download.php`, my data type result is `string 'string'` too. I need to **differentiate** them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a successful curl_exec with RETURNTRANSFER will always be a string. You need to find another method to determine what format the string represents.

The standard way to do this within HTTP is using [mime-types](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html). These are often added to additional headers in the HTTP response.

In download.php add a header

```
$file = "G:/../xxx.tgz";

// Open the file in a binary mode
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

// output content-type header
header('Content-Type: '. mime_content_type($file));
// Dump the tar and stop the script
$success = fpassthru($fp);

fclose($fp);

if(!$success) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to downlonad');
}
```

And in  curl.php look for the content-type header - note this is a very rough script which should work in your case and point you in the right direction.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/.../download.php");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response);

$headers = explode("\r\n", $headers);
$contentType = "";
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    $headerParts = explode(':', $header);
    if($headerParts[0] == 'Content-Type') {
        $contentType = $headerParts[1];
    }
}

var_dump($contentType);
```